# Get Data from CRM online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am new in CRM. I have to move data from CRM to sharepoint online.

How can i get data from crm online?

How to create entity for online crm. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Scribe Online](http://www.scribesoft.com/scribe_online) to 
replicate data down from CRM Online to a local SQL Server instance

They have a [blog post](http://blog.scribesoft.com/integrating-dynamics-crm-and-microsoft-sharepoint/) which shows the process of pushing the data into SharePoint using its web services